# Windows Phone 8 Camera App: Start and stop the same video recording stream in different methods

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, camera, stream, async-await

I am trying to implement a simple camera app for Windows Phone 8.0

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private const CameraSensorLocation SENSOR_LOCATION = CameraSensorLocation.Back;

    private AudioVideoCaptureDevice _videoDevice = null;

    // ... ctor and camInitialization methods etc.

    private async void CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        try{
            StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("videos", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            StorageFile storageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Video.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

            using (var s = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                _videoDevice.VideoEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureVideoFormat.H264;
                await _videoDevice.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(s);

                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                // I want  the following 3 lines to be executed when I press the button again
                await _videoDevice.StopRecordingAsync();
                await s.FlushAsync();
                s.AsStream().Dispose();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
        }   
    }
}
```

everything works fine - I create a file in the IsolatedStorage of the phone, open it as a Stream and start Recording a Video to the stream. Now, I obviously don't want to have a `Thread.Sleep` to define the Video length, but I want to stop the recording when I press the button again.

My Problem is, I have no clue how I can do that, cause I have an open stream that will be closed when the function is ending.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the using block and create property/variable for your stream. This way it can be stopped from multiple methods. However you must handle disposing manually.

You can also check out video recording sample provided by Microsoft - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394041%28v=vs.105%29.aspx